# Find known string in file then add string prior to it

Tags: php, string, replace

I need to find a known string inside a config file and then add some content(another string) prior to this.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Example:

```
$findString = "Find Me";
$newString = "String To Add";
```

filetomodify.config

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
Find Me
cccccccccccccc
ddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

Desired outcome:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
String To Add
Find Me
cccccccccccccc
ddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

I've been using fopen to access the file but this only allows to prepend or append content, by default with fwrite. I can't currently think of an efficient way to meet my requirement.

Comment: In general, with file i/o, you're going to wind up re-writing the end of the file after the insert.  You can read/write blocks at a time to make it quicker though.  (the `r+` option should let you use `seek()` and write in the middle of the file, overwrite only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question essentially needs two answers:

- One for the case, that the file is guaranteed to be small enough to be read into memory
- One for the opposite case

The first version is easily achieved by

```
$s=file_get_contents('/path/to/file');
$s=str_replace("\nFind Me\n", "\nString To Add\nFind Me\n", $s);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file', $s);
```

The second version needs more work, along the lines of

```
$in=fopen('/path/to/file', 'rb');
$out=fopen('/path/to/file.tmp', 'wb');
while (($s = fgets($in)) !== false) {
  if ($s == "Find Me") $s="String To Add\nFind Me";
  fputs($out, $s);
}
fclose($in);
fclose($out);
unlink('/path/to/file');
rename('/path/to/file.tmp', '/path/to/file');
```

Comment: It's only a few kb so should be ok to load into memory.

Comment: @PhillHealey - then Version 1 should be quite fast and reliable

Comment: Great! I knew it'd be simple. Another not case of not being able to see the woods for the trees. Thanks for providing the two options.

Answer (score 1):

If files are small you could read the entire file using `file_get_contents` and use the `preg_replace()` function.

For instance;

```
$new = preg_replace( "/$findString/", "$newString\n$findString", $originalContentAsString );
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yup, string replace is probably the better option in this case.